# Write byte 0 in a binary file in C

Tags: c, file, fwrite

I have to write a n numbers of bytes in a binary file in C, how can I write it? All the bytes has to be 0.

I am writting a char, but I dont know if this is the correct way.

```
int i;
for(i=0; i < 200; i++){
    fwrite(0, sizeof(char), 1, file);
}
```

Comment: Read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of `fwrite` must be a valid pointer.

You can use `fputc` to write an immediate character (byte) into a file like this:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i < 200; i++){
    fputc(0, file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the buffer which contains the data to write. In your case you can store '\0' in a char variable and pass its address.

```
char c = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    fwrite(&c, sizeof c, 1, file);
```

Another (more efficient) solution is create a buffer of 200 elements directly:

```
char buff[200] = {0}; // declare array with 200 '\0' bytes
fwrite(buff, 1, 200, file);
```